# monday.com Access token received via OAuth is not valid to make API requests

Tags: monday.com

I have a monday.com App  in place. The current flow is as below.

- App in installed in the account
- Add any recipe to board
- User will be redirected to sign-in page
- Login to our product
- Redirected back to Monday to authorize the app. Here will monday.com will list out required permissions and all.
- Once authorized, monday.com will provide us with an access token, token type, etc…

The problem, with this access_token, not able to make API calls to monday.com.

API Endpoint: `https://api.monday.com/v2`

Method: POST

Authentication type: Bearer token

Request Body:

```
{
    "query" : "{ boards (limit:1) {id name} }"
}
```

Received response from monday

```
{
    "errors": [
        "Not Authenticated"
    ]
}
```

As I understand monday OAuth does not have refresh token logic and access token will stay as long as app in installed in the account.

Posted the same question in [monday.com as well](https://community.monday.com/t/access-token-received-via-oauth-is-not-valid-to-make-api-requests/28323)

Answer (score 0):

For javascript users, they can make use of the npm package [monday-sdk-js][https://www.npmjs.com/package/monday-sdk-js].
Here is an example for calling the endpoint for displaying the data. Provide your access token and run the script.

```
const mondaySdk = require("monday-sdk-js");
const monday = mondaySdk();
const your_token ="<--your_access_token-->";
monday.setToken(your_token);

// query to display

monday.api(`query { boards (limit:1) {id name} }`).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });


  


  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/monday-sdk-js
```